# Accessing private members of a derived class C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, member, derived-class

I am trying to access derived class' private members via an object of the base class. Here is what I'm trying to do :

```
 class A {

      private:

           int a, b;

      public:
           A(_a, _b) : a(_a), b(_b) {}
           int getA() { return a; }
           int getB() { return b; }
 };

 class B : public A {

      private:
           int c;

      public:
           B(_a, _b, _c) : A(_a, _b), c(_c) {}
           int getC() { return c; }

 };

 vector<A*> objects;
 A* retVal = new B(1,2,3);
 objects.push_back(retVal);
```

Now how is it possible to access this?

```
 objects[0] -> getC();
```

I am a little confused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are sure that the object in the vector is a 'B' instance you can cast

Comment: The line `int getA() { return a; }` should be `int getA() const { return a; }`

Comment: I tried casting it but I still get the same error : class a does not have member c

Comment: BTW, `virtual ~A()` is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the object is actually of derived type `B`, you can do this:

```
static_cast<B*>(objects[0])->getC();
```

If you are wrong and the object is not actually of type `B` (or a subclass of `B`), your program will invoke undefined behavior, so don't do that.

Comment: Also one could use `dynamic_cast<B*>` and a `nullptr` check to determine what the actual derived class is.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a pure virtual function in your base class

```
 class A {

      private:

           int a, b;

      public:
           A(_a, _b) : a(_a), b(_b) {}
           int getA() { return a; }
           int getB() { return b; }
           virtual int getC() = 0;
 };

 class B : public A {

      private:
           int c;

      public:
           B(_a, _b, _c) : A(_a, _b), c(_c) {}
           virtual int getC() { return c; }

 };
```

Comment: I have other derived classes too. I think this does not work. Is there another way?

Comment: @user3279394 _'Is there another way?'_ Not in a simple straightforward manner. May be inheritance isn't the right instrument to solve your real use case. Hard to give you advice without knowing it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any clean way to do what you want. I think it is at odds with the way inheritance is meant to be used in c++: if your derived class adds new methods then it should really be regarded as a new type, i.e. something more than just a morphing of the base type. (What you are trying to do is more objective-C-like philosophy, where methods calls are resolved runtime.)
My suggestion is to reconsider your design and keep B-object conceptually separated from A-objects.