# Accessing derived class methods from a vector of type base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

In my program I have a class with several derived classes. I'm am trying to store all instances of the derived classes in a vector. To do this the vector has the base class type, and they are all stored there fine. However when I try to access a method that belongs to a derived class from the vector I cannot do it as the base class does not have this method. Is there any way around this? Example code below.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base
{

};

class derived
    :public base
{

public:
    void foo()
    {
        cout << "test";
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<base*> *bar = new vector<base*>();
    bar->push_back(new derived);
    bar->push_back(new derived);

    bar[0].foo();
}
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with `vector`. You can't call a derived type's method from a base class pointer. You can only call the methods of the base.

Comment: We had [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853357/accessing-private-members-of-a-derived-class-c/23853498#comment36710653_23853498) already today?

Comment: It's `int main`, not `void main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `foo` a `virtual` method in `base` class. Then override it in `derived` class.

```
class base{
     public:
        virtual void foo()=0;
};

class derived
:public base
{

public:
void foo() overide
{
    cout << "test";
} 
};
```

You can now call `foo` with pointer/reference to `base`

```
 int main(){  // return type of main should be int, it is portable and standard
  vector<base*> bar;  // using raw pointer is error prone
  bar.push_back(new derived);
  bar.push_back(new derived);

  bar[0]->foo(); 
  return 0;
}
```

Learn [polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) and [virtual function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function)